# obtaining a list of prime numbers in Ada

Tags: ada

I have made a program for obtaining a list of prime numbers in ADA and using the following online compiler:

https://rextester.com/l/ada_online_compiler

My code is the following:

```
  --GNAT 8.3.0

with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;


procedure prime is
    function isPrime(n:in Integer) return Boolean is
    begin
        for i in 2..n loop
            if n mod i=0 then 
                return False;
            end if;
        end loop;
        return True;
    end isPrime;
    
begin
    for i in 1..100 loop
        if isPrime(i)=True then
            Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(Integer'Image(i));
        end if;
        Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(Integer'Image(i));
    end loop;
end prime;
```

And instead of printing a list of primes it only print 1. I have program the same code in C and no problem at all.

Comment: Can you show the contents of `source.adb` ? You are showing above those of `prime.adb`

Comment: I will add a screenshot, because this is a online compiler, thanks

Comment: The function is not called `prime`...

Comment: silly of me, I have fixed it, unfortunately it only prints 1

Comment: Small note: is `isPrime` returns a boolean, there is no need to explicitly check if it is `True` or `False`. You can write `if isPrime(i) then ...`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your for loop in isPrime() checks every value higher than one as "n mod n = 0" which will cause you to return false for every value higher than 1.  Change the for loop condition to

```
for i in 2..(n-1) loop
```

and work from there

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Jere's [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71984509/230513), several [simple primality tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Simple_methods) will simplify the divisibility test in the `isPrime` loop:

- The only even prime, 2, can be handled immediately:

  ```
    if N = 2 then
       return True;
    end if;
  ```
- All remaining even numbers can be eliminated:

  ```
    if N mod 2 = 0 then
       return False;
    end if;
  ```
- This leaves odd numbers in the range 3 .. √N to check:

  ```
  for i in 3 .. Positive (Sqrt (Float (N))) loop
     if N mod i = 0 then
        …
     end if;
  end loop;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

It is even better by defining a `Prime_Number` type containing prime numbers.

```
subtype Prime_Number is Positive range 2 .. Positive'Last with
   Dynamic_Predicate => (for all I in 2 .. (Prime_Number / 2) 
      => (Prime_Number mod I) /= 0);
```

Then, use the code segment below to print out all prime numbers between 2 .. 100 range.

```
for Index in Positive range 2 .. 100 loop
   if Index in Prime_Number then
      Put_Line ("Prime number: " & Index'Image);
   end if;
end loop;
```